# Attaching validation results to `context` or `response` in Apollo Server

Tags: javascript, validation, graphql, apollo-server

I'm trying to attach the results of a `validationRule` to either the `response` or `context` in Apollo Server.

The background is that I'm adding a query complexity validation rule (using [this graphql-validation-complexity](https://github.com/4Catalyzer/graphql-validation-complexity) lib), but before adding a validation error I'd like to track the average complexity of normal user queries. I'm writing logs with an [extension](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/tree/master/packages/graphql-extensions) so that I have access to the `context` and `response`, so getting the results of the validation onto either of those (regardless of the validation passing or not) would be ideal.

Validation plugins appear to have access to something called the `validationContext` (here's [the source of that from the graphql.js lib](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/master/src/validation/ValidationContext.js#L161_)), but that isn't the same as the request `context`, so I'm having trouble bubbling the validation results up.

Here's a test case, with a few comments about what I'm trying to do:

```
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require('apollo-server');
const { createComplexityLimitRule } = require('graphql-validation-complexity');
const { GraphQLExtension } = require('graphql-extensions');

// an example of using an extension for logging
class Logger extends GraphQLExtension {
    willSendResponse(o) {
        const { context, graphqlResponse } = o;
        console.log(`This is where I'm doing logging, and would like to access the query cost`);
    }
}

const books = [
    {
        title: 'Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets',
        author: 'J.K. Rowling',
    },
    {
        title: 'Jurassic Park',
        author: 'Michael Crichton',
    },
];

const typeDefs = gql`
    type Book {
        title: String
        author: String
    }

    type Query {
        books: [Book]
    }
`;

const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        books: () => books,
    },
};

const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    extensions: [() => new Logger()],
    validationRules: [
        createComplexityLimitRule(1000, {
            onCost: (cost, validationContext) => {
                // how can I get this onto `context` or `request`?
                console.log(`query cost: ${cost}`);
            },
        }),
    ],
});

server.listen().then(({ url }) => {
    console.log(`Server ready at ${url}`);
});
```

And a `package.json` to install from:

```
{
  "name": "apollo-question",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "apollo-server": "2.3.1",
    "graphql": "14.1.1",
    "graphql-extensions": "^0.4.1",
    "graphql-validation-complexity": "^0.2.4"
  }
}
```

(to run this example, make a new folder, write the second block to `package.json`, write the first block to `index.js`, run `npm install`, then `npm run start`)

Does anyone know how to attach the results of a `validationRule` to the `context` or `response`?